# Finding a segment fault in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I had this code that completely worked on the clang compiler a month ago, and now it segment faults. Using gdb, I just get

```
#0  0x00007ffff7a85bf9 in __GI__IO_vfscanf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7a96b8b in __isoc99_fscanf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000000000401470 in main ()
```

and when I try to select a specific frame it doesn't reveal anything else.

Below I posted the entire code. Has clang been updated? Has fscanf been changed? I'm not sure what has changed to cause this fault.
Any help revealing where the fault is would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


//a stack for if else endif
#define MAXSTACK 20
#define EMPTYSTACK -1
int top = EMPTYSTACK;
int items[MAXSTACK];
int counter = 0;
int ifcounter = 0;
int temp = 0;

void cpush(int c) {
   items[++top] = c;
}
int cpop() {
   return items[top--];
}
int cfull()  {
   return top+1 == MAXSTACK;
}
int cempty()  {
   return top == EMPTYSTACK;
}

int push(int n, FILE *write){
  if ((n <= 255 && n >= -255))
    fprintf (write, "\tCONST R3, #%d\n", n);
  if (n > 255 || n < -255) {
    int d = n & 0xFF;
    fprintf (write, "\tCONST R3, #%d\n", d);
    //unsigned short int d = ((unsigned short int) n);
    //d &= 0xFF00;
    n = n >> 8;
    fprintf (write, "\tHICONST R3, #%u\n", n);
  }
  fprintf (write, "\tSTR R3, R6, #-1\n");
  fprintf (write, "\tADD R6, R6, #-1\n");
  return 1;
}

int pop(int n, FILE *write){
  fprintf (write, "\t;; pop %d      \n", n);
  fprintf (write, "\tADD R6, R6, #%d    \n", n);
  return 0;
}

int compare(char *s, FILE *write, char* filename){
    counter++;
    fprintf (write, "\t;; %s\n", s);
    fprintf (write, "\tLDR R0, R6, #0 \n");
    fprintf (write, "\tLDR R1, R6, #1 \n");
    pop(2, write);
    //fprintf (write, "\tSUB R0, R0, R1 \n");
    fprintf (write, "\tCMP R0, R1   \n");
    if (strcmp(s , "lt") == 0)
    fprintf (write, "\tBRn TRUE%d_%s    \n", counter, filename);
    else if (strcmp(s , "le") == 0)
    fprintf (write, "\tBRnz TRUE%d_%s   \n", counter, filename);
    else if (strcmp(s , "eq") == 0)
    fprintf (write, "\tBRz TRUE%d_%s    \n", counter, filename);
    else if (strcmp(s , "ge") == 0)
    fprintf (write, "\tBRzp TRUE%d_%s   \n", counter, filename);
    else fprintf (write,"\tBRp TRUE%d_%s    \n", counter, filename); //gt
    push(0, write);
    fprintf (write, "\tBRnzp FALSE%d_%s \n", counter, filename);
    fprintf (write, "TRUE%d_%s      \n", counter, filename);
    push(1, write);
    fprintf (write, "FALSE%d_%s     \n", counter, filename);
    return 1;
}

int printdefun (char *s, FILE *write){
    fprintf (write, ";;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;%s;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;\n", s);
  fprintf (write, "\t.CODE\n");
  fprintf (write, "\t.FALIGN\n");
  fprintf (write, "%s\n", s);
  fprintf (write, "\t;; prologue\n");
  fprintf (write, "\tSTR R7, R6, #-2  ;; save return address\n");
  fprintf (write, "\tSTR R5, R6, #-3  ;; save base pointer\n");
  fprintf (write, "\tADD R6, R6, #-3\n");
  fprintf (write, "\tADD R5, R6, #0\n");
  fprintf (write, "\t;; function body\n");
  return 1;
}

int printreturn (FILE *write){
  fprintf (write, "\t;; epilogue\n");
  fprintf (write, "\tLDR R7, R6, #0 ;; \n");
  fprintf (write, "\tADD R6, R6, #1 ;; \n");
  fprintf (write, "\tSTR R7, R5, #2 ;; \n");
  fprintf (write, "\tADD R6, R5, #0 ;; \n");
  fprintf (write, "\tLDR R5, R6, #0 ;; \n");
  fprintf (write, "\tLDR R7, R6, #1 ;; \n");
  fprintf (write, "\tADD R6, R6, #2 ;; \n");
  fprintf (write, "\tJMPR R7\n");
  return 1;
}

int arith(FILE *write, char *s){
  fprintf (write, "\t;; %s      \n", s);
  fprintf (write, "\tLDR R0, R6, #0 \n");
  fprintf (write, "\tLDR R1, R6, #1 \n");
  pop(2, write);
  fprintf (write, "\t%s R0, R0, R1  \n", s);
  fprintf (write, "\tSTR R0, R6, #-1  \n");
  fprintf (write, "\tADD R6, R6, #-1  \n");
  return 1;
}

int not(FILE *write){
  fprintf (write, "\t;; NOT     \n");
  fprintf (write, "\tLDR R0, R6, #0 \n");
  pop(1, write);
  fprintf (write, "\tNOT R0, R0   \n");
  fprintf (write, "\tSTR R0, R6, #-1  \n");
  fprintf (write, "\tADD R6, R6, #-1  \n");
  return 1;
}


/*Makes a new file without comments or anything following
 * also turns lone + into p and lone - into m
 */
int removeComments(char* readname){
  FILE *read;
  read = fopen(readname,"r");
  FILE *write;
  write = fopen("file.j", "wb");
  int c;
  int read_semicolon = 0;

    while ((c = fgetc(read)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            fprintf(write, "%c", c);
            read_semicolon = 0;
        }
        else if (c == ';')
            read_semicolon = 1;
        else if (!read_semicolon) {
          if(c == '+'){
            int t = fgetc(read);
            if (t == ' ' || t ==';' || t == '\t')
              c = 'p';
            ungetc(t, read);
          }
          else if(c == '-'){
            int t = fgetc(read);
            if (t == ' ' || t ==';' || t == '\t'){
              c = 'm';
              ungetc(t, read);
            }
            else if (t == '0'){
              int t = fgetc(read);
              if (t == 'x'){
                fprintf(write, "OX ");
                c = '-';
              } else ungetc(t, read);
            }
            else ungetc(t, read);
          }
          else if(c == '0'){
            int t = fgetc(read);
            if (t == 'x'){
            fprintf(write, "OX");
            c = ' ';
            }else ungetc(t, read);
          }
            fprintf(write, "%c", c);
        }
        /* else suppressed because read_semicolon is true */
    }
    fclose(read);
    fclose(write);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  removeComments(argv[1]);
  FILE *read;               //file to read in
  read = fopen("file.j","r");

  char *filename = strtok(argv[1], ".");  //gets rid of the . and beyond
  strcat (filename,".asm");         //makes the name .asm via concatenation
  FILE *write;  
  write = fopen(filename, "wb");

  char *s;
  int c;
  int d;
  int n = 0;
  unsigned int u;
    char *asmname = strtok(argv[1], ".");
  while(feof(read) == 0){
    if (fscanf(read, "0x%s", s) == 1){
      char* hexstring = s;
      long int y = strtol(hexstring, (char**)0, 0);
      //int y = strtod(s, &endp);
      push(y, write);
    }
      if(fscanf(read,"%d", &d)) {
        /* this makes sure that ints preceding "pick" etc are not
         * counted as ints that are pushed onto the stack. Further this makes sure
         * the testing for this does not "eat" and of the words in the file
         */ 
        /*const long pos = ftell(read); // stores current position
        //checks if the next thing 
        if (fscanf(read,"%s", s)){
        if ((strcmp(s , "pick") == 0 || (strcmp(s , "eq") == 0))){
          //fprintf (write, "%d %s called\n", d, s);
        }
        else {
          push(d, write);
          //undo the word we "ate" 
          fseek(read, pos, SEEK_SET);
        }
      } else */ push(d, write);
      } 
      else if (fscanf(read,"%s", s)){ 
        if (strcmp(s , "defun") == 0) {
          fscanf(read,"%s", s);
          printdefun (s, write);
        }
        else if (strcmp(s , "return") == 0) {
          printreturn (write);
        }
        else if (strcmp(s , "p") == 0) {
          arith(write, "ADD");
        }
        else if (strcmp(s , "m") == 0) {
          arith(write, "SUB");
        }
        else if (strcmp(s , "*") == 0) {
          arith(write, "MUL");
        }
        else if (strcmp(s , "/") == 0) {
          arith(write, "DIV");
        }
        else if (strcmp(s , "%") == 0) {
          arith(write, "MOD");
        }
        else if (strcmp(s , "and") == 0) {
          arith(write, "AND");
        }
        else if (strcmp(s , "or") == 0) {
          arith(write, "OR");
        }
        else if (strcmp(s , "not") == 0) {
          not(write);
        }
        else if (strcmp(s , "drop") == 0) {
          fprintf (write, "\t;; drop\n");
          pop(1, write);
        }
        else if (strcmp(s , "dup") == 0) {
          fprintf (write, "\t;; dup\n");
          fprintf (write, "\tLDR R0, R6, #0 \n");
          fprintf (write, "\tSTR R0, R6, #-1  \n");
          fprintf (write, "\tADD R6, R6, #-1  \n");
        }
        else if (strcmp(s , "swap") == 0) {
          fprintf (write, "\t;; swap\n");
          fprintf (write, "\tLDR R0, R6, #0 \n");
          fprintf (write, "\tLDR R1, R6, #1 \n");
          fprintf (write, "\tSTR R0, R6, #1 \n");
          fprintf (write, "\tSTR R1, R6, #0 \n");
        }
        else if (strcmp(s , "rot") == 0) {
          fprintf (write, "\t;; rot\n");
          fprintf (write, "\tLDR R0, R6, #0 \n");
          fprintf (write, "\tLDR R1, R6, #1 \n");
          fprintf (write, "\tLDR R2, R6, #2 \n");
          fprintf (write, "\tSTR R2, R6, #0 \n");
          fprintf (write, "\tSTR R1, R6, #2 \n");
          fprintf (write, "\tSTR R0, R6, #1 \n");
        }
        else if (strcmp(s , "pick") == 0){
          fprintf (write, "\t;; pick\n");
          fprintf (write, "\tLDR R0, R6, #0 \n");
          fprintf (write, "\tADD R1, R6, R0 \n");
          fprintf (write, "\tADD R1, R1, #1 \n");
          pop(1, write);
          fprintf (write, "\tLDR R2, R1, #0 \n");
          fprintf (write, "\tSTR R2, R6, #-1  \n");
          fprintf (write, "\tADD R6, R6, #-1  \n");
        }
        else if (strcmp(s , "lt") == 0 || strcmp(s , "le") == 0 
          || strcmp(s , "eq") == 0 || strcmp(s , "ge") == 0 
          || strcmp(s , "gt") == 0){
          compare(s, write, asmname);
        }
        else if (strcmp(s , "if") == 0) {
          ifcounter+=2;
          cpush(ifcounter);
          fprintf (write, "\tLDR R0, R6, #0 \n");
          pop(1, write);
          fprintf (write, "\tCMPI R0, #0    \n");
          fprintf (write, "\tBRz ELSE%d_%s  \n", ifcounter, asmname);
        }
        else if (strcmp(s , "else") == 0) {
          ifcounter = cpop();
          fprintf (write, "\tBRnzp ELSE%d_%s  \n", (ifcounter + 1), asmname);
          fprintf (write, "ELSE%d_%s    \n", ifcounter, asmname);
          cpush(++ifcounter);
        }
        else if (strcmp(s , "endif") == 0) {
          ifcounter = cpop();
          if (temp < ifcounter)
            temp = ifcounter;
          fprintf (write, "ELSE%d_%s    \n", ifcounter, asmname);
          ifcounter = temp;
        }
        else if (strcmp(s , "OX") == 0) {
          fscanf(read,"%s", s);
          //int aInt = 368;
          //char str[16];
          //sprintf(str, "%d", d);
          //char *num = d;
          long int li = strtol (s,NULL,16);
          d = (int) li;
          push(d, write);
        }
        else {
          fprintf (write, "\tJSR %s\n", s);
        }
      }
      //else if(fscanf(read,"%x", &u)) {}
  } //while(c != EOF);  
  fclose(read);
  fclose(write);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The dump seems to indicate the problem in an `fscanf` call. Check that you've properly allocated the buffers you're writing to, and that they are of adequate length to hold what you're scanning in.

Comment: Please use a debugger, and narrow the problem down.

Comment: try `valgrind`... It can shed some decent light on things..

Comment: `char *s;` ... `if (fscanf(read, "0x%s", s) == 1){`  need allocate memory

Comment: As for the why this used to work and now it doesn't, memory corruption is very dependent on how things are laid out in memory by the compiler/linker. If this changed for any reason, it could reveal a new bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies here:
`if (fscanf(read, "0x%s", s) == 1){`

The `s` variable is simply defined as `char *s;`, which means there wasn't any memory allocated for the string it should point to, so it holds an arbitrary value. No clue why this worked with clang previously as you say; it should've segfaulted earlier on.

Comment: How would I fix it? Simply mallocing and freeing sizeof char* doesn't work..?

Comment: Define it as follows:
`char s[ 20 ];`

No need to `malloc()` and `free()` it, since it's only used in that one function, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, you should use gdb to set breakpoints and at least have less code to go through, but it looks like  char *s in main() is used in an fscanf() without any memory allocated to it (witch is usually what segmentation faults are). If you want to use it as a string use

```
 x = amount of characters
 char s[x] //this will make an array(pointer) of chars
```

or

```
 char *s = (char *) malloc(x * sizeof(char)); //allocates memory to the pointer
```

Also i didn't go through the entire code so there may be more.